# Opening a hyperlink in a new tab in ASP.NET

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have a hyperlink on my page and I would like it to automatically open in a new tab when clicked, how would I do this? If this is not possible I will accept new window.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This depends on how the browser treats the `target` attribute on the `a` (anchor) tag

When `target="_blank"`, older browsers, which don't have tabbing, will open a new window.

Newer browsers, however, will use this to open a new tab.

Comment: I'm using Chrome so other browsers don't really bother me, just a little project

Comment: In which case, I believe `<a target="_blank">` will suffice

Answer (score 14):

The syntax is following:

```
<a href="http://www.someurl.com" target="_blank">
```

This will open the page in new page or tab this depends on browser configuration.

Answer (score 5):

add

```
 target="_blank" in your link.
```

If you want links on whole page to be open in new tab you can use.

```
<head>
 <title></title>
 <base target="_blank"/>
</head>
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS3 offers a [target-new](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-hyperlinks/#the-target-new)  property for which you can specify `window | tab | none`:

> If a user wanted to have new windows open in new tabs instead, she
>   could use the following user style sheet to do so:
>
> ```
> * { target-new: tab ! important }
> ```

Comment: As of Setember 2013 this attribute isn't supported in any major browsers. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_target-new.asp

Answer (score 3):

Use the following

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hplStandard" runat="server"  ForeColor="Green"  
 Font-Bold="True" Target="_blank">Standard Report</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 2):

set the property Target to _blank